# Products Configuration Wizard - Failed to register SharePoint Services

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, feature-upgrade, configuration-wizard

**Setup:**

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- SQL Server 2008 R2
- SharePoint Server 2010

Last successfully installed and configured update: [Service Pack 2 for Microsoft SharePoint 2010 (KB2687453)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39672).

Current Build: 14.0.7015.1000

**Problem:**

I'm having a problem running the SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard. I recently installed the [Security Update for 2010 Microsoft Business Productivity Servers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42853). This should bring the build to 14.0.7123.5000. After installing the update, I ran the Products Configuration Wizard. The Wizard failed on step 5 with the following error:

> Failed to register SharePoint Services.

I dug deeper into the ULS Error logs and found the following error:

ULS Log Error:

> 09/30/2014 19:16:57  8  ERR                    Failed to register SharePoint services.
>   An exception of type System.InvalidOperationException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
>      at Microsoft.Office.HtmlTrans.HtmlTrServiceDeserializationSecurityHelper.EnsureAcknowledgedRunningOnAppServer(Boolean registryKeyLookupResult, ULSCat serviceCategory, Boolean hasExceptionMessage)
>      at Microsoft.Office.Server.Conversions.SPDocConvServiceInstanceUpdaterJobDefinition.UpdateLauncherServiceInstance(LauncherServiceInstance lsi, Boolean fEnableService, Boolean fCycleService, Boolean fCallUpdate)
>      at Microsoft.Office.Server.Conversions.LauncherServiceInstance.Provision()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServiceInstanceInConfigDB(Boolean provisionTheServiceInstanceToo, String serviceInstanceRegistryKeyName, Object sharepointServiceObject)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServiceInstances(Boolean provisionTheServiceInstancesToo, String serviceRegistryKeyName, Object sharepointServiceObject)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServices(Boolean provisionTheServicesToo)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.Run()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

I checked the prerequisites for this particular update and it said SharePoint Server 2010 SP1 and SharePoint Server 2010 SP2 were required. I've installed and successfully configured both of these updates. Unfortunately, I don't understand what the above error means and have been unable to find any resources that have worked so far.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: did you try to restart the server? also try to stop all the services related to SharePoint manually i.e SharePoint timer services, Admin services, Worldwideweb, search , tracing etc from services console.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Thank you for the fast reply. I have restarted the server multiple times. I also tried running the configuration wizard manually from the console using `PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force` and it completed successfully. However, the build number did not increase in Central Admin. I'll try shutting down the services manually before running the wizard and report back how that goes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: War10ck, Good news and bad news. Good news: I was able to get through the configuration wizard by adding the values you have above as DWORD values in the registry, not as new keys.
Bad news: I went down this path because when I try to open a user homepage or central admin I get a 503 and the application pool stops. I've also tried clearing the config cache with no luck.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I resolved the issue. It appears based on the Microsoft Knowledge Base information that:

> Some document-conversion services in SharePoint Server are not secure when they run in a particular environment

In order to allow the services to continue to run, the following registry key needs to be added:

```
Name: AcknowledgedRunningOnAppServer
Type: DWORD
Value: 1
```

to the following locations:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office Server\{version}\LauncherSettings
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office Server\{version}\LoadBalancerSettings
```

replacing `{version}` with your version number (14 for me).

After adding these keys, re-run the Products Configuration Wizard and it should succeed.

Comment: I wonder how you figured that this register should be added any link...+1

Comment: Microsoft KB for this issue is at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2910363

Answer (score 2):

I was still having the same error, even after adding the registry entries.

It turns out that the Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service was disabled, once I enabled it and started, I re-ran the Configuration Wizard again and it went past stage 5.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue where the configuration wizard would fail at:   "Failed to register SharePoint Services."

Following Steve's suggesting I also found that the Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service was disabled.   I enabled it, re-ran the sharepoint configuration wizard with this powershell command:   psconfig -cmd standalongconfig

It finished!!!   Wtth this:   Successfully completed the SharePoint prodcuts configuration.